# php - How to find a random string in a page source?

Tags: php, curl

There is a webpage and this is all that is in

```
    //html code
    random number: 76582377
    //html code
```

Each time the page is refreshed, the random number is new as well.

How can I grab the random number since it is dynamic? It is always 8 letters long though.
I am using cURL, if that will help.

Thanks.

Comment: The string `random number:` literally precedes the 8 digit number?

Comment: You can use DOM. What's your HTML code like

Comment: regex is the droid you are looking for, but we can't help without the complete or relevant html code.

Comment: parsing html with regex is a broken crazy droid with homicidal tendency

Comment: IT's just a lot of regular code for design, etc

Comment: Can we see the HTML that prints your random number?

Comment: It's surrounded by HTML, but isn't in any HTML. Just a plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example with regular expressions.  This will match `random number:`, followed by 1+ whitespace, followed by the 8 digit alphanumeric (`[\w]{8}`) we want to match.  If we just want this to be digits (not alphanumeric), you can modify the `\w` to `\d`.  Also, you let the whole thing be case-insensitive (`RandoM nUMBer: 12345678`) by appending a `i` after the ending `/`.

```
$html = "<html>\nrandom number: 76582377\n</html";
if(preg_match('/random number:\s+([\w]{8})/', $html, $matches)) {
    $code = $matches[1];

    var_dump($code);
    // string(8) "76582377"
}
```

If the `random code` is always in a certain element, it would be more efficient to use [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/domdocument) though.  We can't help without more of an example..

Comment: Please don't miss my note about `DOMDocument`, OP.  If your code always appears in `<span id="code">random number: 12345678</span>` (or something similar), then you shouldn't be using RegEx.

Comment: Parsing HTML with Regex? Not good practice I believe. :(

Comment: @CoderX90 do you not see my note and comment?  This is the best answer we can give with OP's question..since OP doesn't provide any HTML structure, this is pretty much parsing a String with regex.

Comment: The random number isn't in any HTML, just surrounded by it. This should work. Thanks!